# How to get specific element in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

```
<Employee Id="01">
<Name> ABC </Name>
<Telephone> 123456789</Telephone>
<Age> 25</Age>
<MartialStatus> False </MartialStatus>
</Employee>

<Employee Id="02">
<Name> XYZ </Name>
<Telephone> 00000000</Telephone>
<Age> 25</Age>
<MartialStatus> False </MartialStatus>
</Employee>
```

Using Telephone number how to find particular Employee name in c#, suppose i have one XML file who have more then 100 employee details now using particulate employee telephone number find all employee details. How it's possible?

Comment: What have you tried and where were you stuck?

Comment: I have multiple employee details in xml file now i want to any particular employee details using his\her telephone number in c#

Comment: I've updated my answer should work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list ofemployes using specific telephone number you can try this:

```
XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
var employee = xmlDoc.Descendants("Employee").Where(x => x.Element("Telephone")?.Value == "123456789").ToList();
```

And here is a list of ids:

```
List<string> employeeIDs = res.Select(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a root tag Employees as container for Employee.

```html
<Employees>
  <Employee Id="01">
    <Name> ABC </Name>
    <Telephone>123456789</Telephone>
    <Age> 25</Age>
    <MartialStatus> False </MartialStatus>
  </Employee>
  <Employee Id="02">
    <Name> XYZ </Name>
    <Telephone>00000000</Telephone>
    <Age> 25</Age>
    <MartialStatus> False </MartialStatus>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

```
        // load file XDocument
        XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\t\\My File2.txt");
        /*
         1. Select Employees
            2. Select the Employee Element
               3.Search int this Employee for elements with name "Telephone"
                  4.Extract the value and compare it to your given number
            5. Continue to the next Employee to comaire
         6.Select the first on of all the elements that for filled the search term
         */     

         var employee = _doc.Element("Employees")
            .Elements("Employee")
            .Where(x => x.Element("Telephone")?
            .Value == "00000000")
            .FirstOrDefault();  

         // Get values from elements of Employee
         string name = employee.Element("Name").Value;
         string age = employee.Element("Age").Value;

        MessageBox.Show($"Name: {name}, Age {age}");
```

Comment: I want to all employee details not only name so as per your code i have to use "if" more then 4 or 5 time right??

Comment: You could get the element of the user like that but it is not the best practice. I've updated my question so it can be done in a oneliner :)

Answer (score 0):

Approach using XPath

xml.xml content

```
<Employees>
    <Employee Id="01">
        <Name> ABC </Name>
        <Telephone> 123456789</Telephone>
        <Age> 25</Age>
        <MartialStatus> False </MartialStatus>
    </Employee>

    <Employee Id="02">
        <Name> XYZ </Name>
        <Telephone> 00000000</Telephone>
        <Age> 25</Age>
        <MartialStatus> False </MartialStatus>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

code to access employee by it's telephone number

```
string telNo = " 123456789";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\temp\xml.xml");
var employee = doc.SelectSingleNode("Employees/Employee[Telephone='"+ telNo + "']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to Xml:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"..\XMLfile1.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();

            var elementYouNeed = employees.Where(x => x.Element("Telephone").Value.Trim() == "00000000");
            var nameYouNeed = elementYouNeed.ToList()[0].Element("Name").Value;
```